# ASP.NET MVC - EF Code First doesn't want to create a row in my database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this piece of code:

```
var data = context.Accounts.Where(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name).Select(a => a.UserAddons).SingleOrDefault();
if (data == null)
   data = new UserAddons();
{setting up properties of data}
context.SaveChanges();
```

I want it to create a new row of UserAddons. But it doesn't want to. Do i need to select whole Account entity to do that?

Comment: You need to add the new entity to the context

Answer (score 1):

You're probably forgetting to add the new entity to the context. Try this (not tested):

```
bool isNew = false;
var data = context.Accounts.Where(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name).Select(a => a.UserAddons).SingleOrDefault();

if (data == null)
{
   data = new UserAddons();
   isNew = true;
}  

// setting up properties of data

if(isNew)
    context.Add(data);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yeah. But then i will need to look for the Account entity for the second time, to properly associate entities. :-/

Comment: Then you need to load the Account entity first with the associated UserAddons. If there aren't any, create the new entity.
PS: Are you using a DbContext or ObjectContext?

Comment: I'm using DbContext. Why does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your model correctly, you should add the new `UserAddons` to the `Account`

```
var account = context.Accounts.Where(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name).Single();

if (account.Addons == null)
   account.UserAddons = new UserAddons();

{setting up properties of account.Addons}

context.SaveChanges();
```